# Display files with inode number between 100 and 199 in specific directory

Tags: linux, command, wildcard, ls, wc

I am trying to find all the files with inode number between 100 and 199. I tried it with wildcards like this:

```
ls -i -l 1* | wc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grep` to filter your results:

```
ls -i | grep "^1[0-9][0-9] "
```

With:

- `ls -i`: display inodes then files
- `grep "^1[0-9][0-9] "` (note the space): only take lines beginning with numbers from 100 to 199.